# properly printing out integers from 2 parts

Tags: c++, biginteger, outputstream, objectoutputstream, uint

I have a `uint128_t` class that stores its values as `uint64_t UPPER, LOWER;`, and im not sure how to overload the `operator<<` so that when i pass in `std::cout`, the value will print in decimal properly. currently, im just doing

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, uint128_t const & rhs){
    if (rhs.upper())                  // if the upper value has a non-zero digit
        stream << rhs.upper();

    // i need some way to pad this so that the number of 0s between 
    // upper and lower is correct

    stream << rhs.lower();
    return stream;
```

what should i do?

edit:

example:

if a uint128_t variable has `UPPER = 1` and `LOWER = 1`, i want the stream to contain the decimal value of `(1 << 64) + 1`

Comment: So if `upper` is 1 and `lower` is 2, what should it print?  100,000,000,000,000,000,002? or 18,446,744,073,709,551,618?

Comment: i think i should print 18,446,744,073,709,551,618, since `UPPER` in decimal is `1 << 64`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your division operator and your modulus operator properly implemented, you can do this:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, uint128_t const & rhs){

    if(rhs.upper() == 0)
        return stream << rhs.lower();

    char buffer[50];
    char *cp = buffer + 49;
    *cp = 0;
    while(rhs > 0)
    {
        --cp;
        *cp = (rhs % 10) + '0';
        rhs /= 10;
    }

    return stream << cp;
}
```

Comment: the division and modulous operatos were going to be my next questions :(

Comment: @calccrypto: Well, you should implement those first.